# "Sore ni taru" and "rasen ga gotoku"

Tags: translation

What does "Sore ni taru 'kekka' nano desu" mean?
It takes place here in Fairy Tail manga => http://online.mangaraw.net/Weekly-Shonen-Magazine-Vol-04-05-231-7911.html

And also,  "samazamana omoi to omowaku ga rasen ga gotoku , iri midareru!!" sentence mean?
Again a page from Fairy Tail manga => http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4180/235vs.jpg

I'm confused about these two, I hope anyone can help me, yoroshiku onegaishimasu :)

Comment: Welcome to JLU! Straight translation questions are generally frowned upon (which is probably why you got a downvote). Please tell us which part of these sentences you have trouble with and which part you understand (and the meaning you get from it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The (~~に)たる is [足]{た}る/[足]{た}りる, meaning [十分]{じゅうぶん}な, "to be enough". → [足りる in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/139289/m0u/) #3

「(subject = あの方が予言した大魔闘演武の結果は、)**それ**(= 国の未来を動かす/あの方を信じる)に足る(= のに十分な)**結果**(= あり得ない、特殊な結果)なのです。」
(足る sounds more literary than 足りる.)

2) (~~が)ごとく(=如く) means (~~の)ように, "(just) like~~" → [如く in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/80504/m0u/%E5%A6%82%E3%81%8F/)

[螺旋]{らせん}が[如]{ごと}く can be rephrased as [螺旋]{らせん}のように.
(如く sounds literary/archaic.)

---

・・・ここでつまずいていらっしゃるんじゃないかな～と勝手に思って書きましたけど、的外れだったらすみません。

---

EDIT:

1)

> それに[足]{た}る結果なのです。-- It is that special.

I think the translation is alright; it's saying "It's special enough for that -- It's special enough to make me trust ＊that person＊, special enough to affect the fate of this country".

● In this sentence, the subject is left out; "an unbelievable outcome" i.e. "the results of Daimatou-Enbu which ＊that person＊ has predicted".  
● それ(≠It) refers to あの[方]{かた}を[信]{しん}じる = for me to trust ＊that person＊, and [国]{くに}の[未来]{みらい}を[動]{うご}かす = decide/affect the fate of this country.  
● [足]{た}る means "to be enough", so it's saying "The outcome / The results of Daimatou-Enbu that ＊that person＊ has predicted would be special enough to make me believe in him and entrust him with the fate of this country", i.e. "The outcome is so unlikely to happen that I would have to trust ＊that person＊ and entrust him with the fate of this country if his prediction should come true."


2)

> [様々]{さまざま}な[想]{おも}いと[思惑]{おもわく}が、[螺旋]{らせん}が[如]{ごと}く[入]{い}り[乱]{みだ}れる。
>   Various thoughts and expectations are jumbled together like a spiral

I think it's alright, I'm not sure it's the best translation though... because I don't really understand the nuance of "jumbled together" (Sorry T_T). I think the 入り乱れる here is like [絡]{から}み[合]{あ}う, "to get involved / intertwined" →[絡み合う on 研究社新和英中辞典](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B5%A1%E3%81%BF%E5%90%88%E3%81%86) 
● I think the word [思惑]{おもわく} is used negatively, like... ["ulterior motive"  in Weblio英和対訳辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/ulterior+motive)

Comment: "Sore ni taru" is confusing beacuse all are in written in hiragana. 
And here in English translation (http://www.tenmanga.com/chapter/FairyTail312/306726-22.html)
"It is that special it says" but wouldn't be saying "Sonna tokubetsu na kekka nano desu" if it were saying "It is that special"? 

***What I get it from "SORE NI TARU KEKKA NANO DESU" is "It is such a outcame which is inclined enough to effect". Is it proper?

Comment: AND the other sentence. 
Various thoughts and expectations ga rasen ga gotoku, to be jumbled together!! 

***Does it mean "Various thoughts and expectations are jumbled together like a spiral/circle"?

Comment: Sorry I cannot read kanji withough its furigana T^T I could understand you answer well T.T

Comment: @skip-beat Ahh I'll rewrite it later... sorry I'm sooo lazy I just write everything in Japanese

Comment: Chocolate-san could you contact with me through my mail if it is proper, I wanna ask you sth. (Dear admins I know it's not to place the ask but I cannot find the P.S button so spare me for just once>.>)

Comment: @skip-beat We don't have a private messaging function here on StackExchange... but we do have a chat room where you can talk about Japanese language and ask quick translation questions.

Comment: @skip-beat Hmm maybe you're having trouble translating a private letter or something..? Anyways I'll be back on Friday 31st, hope to see you in the chat room ^^